# how to insert character values in the x axis of a R plot?

Tags: r, plot, character

I'm trying to create a plot in R in which the y axis should show the following values:

```
-0.47, -0.42, -0.38, -0.35, -0.17
```

While the x axis should show the following values (string):

```
"1g", "3m", "2y", "5y", "10y"
```

So I tried the following code:

```
values <- c(-0.47, -0.42, -0.38, -0.35, -0.17)
tenor <- c("1g", "3m", "2y", "5y", "10y")
plot(tenor, values)
```

but I got as a answer:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : i valori 'xlim' devono essere finiti

Inoltre: Warning messages:

1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :

  si è prodotto un NA per coercizione

2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What kind of plot is expected?

Comment: Maybe `plot(factor(tenor, levels = tenor), values)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```r
plot(1:5, values, type = "l", xaxt = "none", xlab = "tenor")
axis(side = 1, at = 1:5, labels = tenor)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I should get a line graph, from 1g to 10y!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `ggplot2` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
values <- c(-0.47, -0.42, -0.38, -0.35, -0.17)
tenor <- factor(c("1g", "3m", "2y", "5y", "10y"),
                levels = c("1g", "3m", "2y", "5y", "10y"),
                ordered = T)
data <- data.frame(values,tenor,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
ggplot(data,aes(x=tenor,y=values,group=1))+geom_line()+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `factor`s with `levels=` then `plot.default` and reconstruct `axis`.

```
plot.default(factor(tenor, levels=tenor), values, 
             type="l", xaxt="n", xlab="tenor", main="My plot")
axis(1, axTicks(1), labels=tenor)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding something to Duck's answer.
If you want to show the value on the y-axis.

```
factor <- c("1g", "3m", "2y", "5y", "10y")
factor <- as.data.frame(factor)
value <- c(-0.47, -0.42, -0.38, -0.35, -0.17)
mydata <- cbind(value, factor)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = factor, y = value, group = 1))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1g", "3m", "2y", "5y", "10y") )+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-0.47, -0.42, -0.38, -0.35, -0.17))
```

[image]